# Flexslider 2 Centering

Tags: html, css

I need to center Flexslider 2, and besides I need to give it a fixed width of 960px, I already did that with:
**HTML5**

```
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li><img src="img/01.jpeg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="img/02.jpeg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="img/03.jpeg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS3**

```
.flexslider{
height:400px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:960px}

.flexslider .slides>li{
display:none;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden}

.flexslider .slides img{
display:block;
width:100%}
```

The Images are 960×400 too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.flexslider` has an error. Imagine - `margin: 0` what? You need specify the units.

Try this:

```
.flexslider{
height:400px;
margin:0px auto;
padding:0;
width:960px}
```

Comment: Nope, it's still at the left.